# Having an Issue with a Login modal when we switch to Mobile NavBar

Tags: html, mobile, uikit

We're having a in issue when our mobile navbar is triggered. Our mobile login button in the mobile navbar can't call the modal. It's effectively the same call being made as in the regular desktop and tablet button, but It does not trigger. The other Navbar buttons on Mobile that do work are anchor's that make modal Hrefs. We've tried a similar thing with the login button trying to call the modal to no avail. Anyone have any Ideas? We need the login modal to be callable from a mobile button, or the whole thing isn't any good for our mobile storefront.

Upon further Inspection it seems that the issue comes from ui-kit's responsiveness.
Can anyone think of what could be done to enable it to appear on screens below 980 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay, at long last I know what the issue was. It turns out that due to a quirk of the original design I was not here for. the login was placed inside the desktop navbar. This navbar disappears when we head on down to mobile sizes. I had to move the login modal outside of the navbar to get it functional.